# When a lead is converted into an opportunity, does the lead get removed from the system?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, leads, custom-report-type

Currently I am building a couple of reports for work and we are trying to build a report for all leads that are logged for this/last FY. Is this possible? If we have 100 leads that 90 of them convert into opportunities, can I still show a report to show that we logged 100 leads or will it show as 10 leads have been logged and 90 opportunities?

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view all the lead conversion related information by creating a report of type: "Leads with Converted Lead Information". Then you can aggregate your information bases on the Converted field value ("YES | NO") to view how many leads have been converted and how many not. Additionally you can create custom formula in your report like `CONVERTED:SUM / RowCount`which should ease your analysis.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your answer. I have utilized the converted field this now shows me clearly which have and have not been converted.